# Arrage layout in a particular number order using CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

[image: Desktop layout]

This is the current layout of my project site using flex-box. I want to arrange the boxes in ascending order like below [image: Mobile Layout] but when i hit mobile screen my left column first gets arranged and then the right column. Is there a way to order it in a sequence given above?

Comment: You can use flex and flex-order https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Can you add some code demonstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'm changing display: from flexbox to grid in max-width 800px

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
            "1"
            "2"
            "3"
            "4"
            "5"
  }
}
.first{
  grid-area: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.second{
  grid-area: 2;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.third{
  grid-area: 3;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.fourth{
  grid-area: 4;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.fifth{
  grid-area: 5;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="first">First</div>
    <div class="third">Third</div>
  </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="second">Second</div>
      <div class="fourth">Fourth</div>
      <div class="fifth">Fifth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want the second div to shift below the first div then third fourth fifth.

Comment: Sorry, not noticed that code not working as expected

Comment: Its okay. Is there any other way?

Comment: How do you think, is it ok to make some elements as absolute? Is all you blocks fixed?